How to know if I look at an address or a local variable just by the bits?
Is it even possible? I was asked about the values that appear on the stack, in a way that without knowing the var type, just by analyzing the bytes I should be able to recognize if it's an address or a local variable.

If you know the compiler, linker and operating system program loader intimately and don't have any kind of address-space randomization enabled, it might be possible. Otherwise, no. And unless you're into "hacking" or "cracking" or other suspicious activities, there's really no need to know.

How would you know the number of bytes that are grouped? 1, 2, 4, or 8.

You can look at the instructions that act on the data to see whether they use it as a pointer int, chars, etc. There is no way to tell from the value.

An address need not be a data pointer, but a code address.

What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you want to know that? What problem would knowing this resolve? Is it just curiosity (that's OK)?

Note that the C Standard doesn't mention any stack (or how to access it using C).

It is not possible to determine the type of a variable just by analyzing its bytes on the stack; this is because bytes on the stack can represent different types of data depending on the context in which they are used. For example, a sequence of bytes on the stack could represent integer, floating-point number, pointer to an object, or even a string. Without additional information about the program's memory layout and data types, it is impossible to determine the type of a variable just by looking at its bytes on the stack. To determine the type of a variable in C, you need to know its declaration and the context in which it is used. Without this information, it is impossible to determine the type of a variable just by analyzing its bytes on the stack.
Here are some sources that explain it is not possible to determine the variable just by analyzing the byte on the stack (up to best of my knowledge)
1."The C Programming Language" by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie, states that "there is no way to tell from the machine-language code of a program whether a given integer is a counter, an array element, or a pointer" (p. 99).
2."Understanding and Using C Pointers" by Richard M. Reese, explains that "it is impossible to determine the type of a pointer just by examining its value" (p. 8).
3."C Programming: A Modern Approach" by K. N. King, states that "there is no way to determine the type of a value just by looking at its bits" (p. 68).
4.Expert C Programming: Deep C Secrets" by Peter van der Linden, explains that "there is no way to tell from the machine code whether a given integer is a counter, an array element, or a pointer" (p. 7).

i googled some sources to support my answer, again up to best of my knowledge! cheers!

If all you're given is an address and told to examine the sequence of bits starting there, then no, there's no (standard, portable, reliable) way to tell what those bits represent.  There is no metadata stored with any runtime object that tells you anything about type, size, lifetime, or anything else.
If you don't even know the byte order of your platform (and whether the addressed byte is the most- or least-significant byte) then you don't even know which sequence of bytes to follow.
What's in memory is a sludge of bytes with no inherent meaning; it is only the code operating on that memory that gives those bytes meaning.
